# How to transfer MySQL database from AMPPS to XAMPP vm Stack

Tags: mysql, xampp, ampps, xampp-vm

I hope you can help me - I used to use AMPPS, but unfortunately due to the Big Sur update it no longer works. so downloaded xampp vm stack. Now can't get a database I need.

I have gone into the Ampps folder and copied out the relevant physical database but copying this into the xampp folder it won't let me. I have attempted to change the permission via `chmod -R 777 /Users/samjacksom/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/var/mysql` and via get info both won't allow me to do so.

Would anyone please have a solution to have I can get my database from the old Ampps?

**UPDATE:**

I have got a Catalina Virtual Machine running with Ampps. And, transferred the files onto there. For the database I copied the db folder from the var folder on ampps on my host to the vm location.

However, when I go into phpmyadmin the database is not unfortunately visible. Could someone advise how I can physically migrate a database?

Comment: Simply do a backup (EXPORT in phpMyAdmin) on one and a restore (IMPORT in phpMyAdmin) on the other

Comment: @RiggsFolly I would in normal circumstances, but unfortunately AMPPS does not work.

Comment: Can you not use your last backup, or is that a silly question

Comment: Sorry no last backup. Thinking of getting a old mac os vm and trying a dump

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just use mysqldump?

```
$ mysqldump -u [user] -p [database_name] > [filename].sql
```

or to get a backup of the entire database:

```
$ mysqldump --all-databases --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false > full-backup-$(date +%F).sql -u root -p
```

then you can restore your backup on new stack just by running:

```
$ mysql -u [user] -p [database_name] < [filename].sql
```

Comment: Can't access the old Ammps, doesn't load on big sur

Comment: do you have any errors or logs? are you sure it's just because of big sur?

Comment: No error log but searching online it seems to be a common fault with big sur and AMPPS :-(